# Django error Coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer

Tags: django, python-2.7

i m getting this error:

```
>>> Child.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    Child.objects.all()
    u = six.text_type(self)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Main found
```

Whenever i try to pull an object from **Child**. i tried to use the unicode but it still gives me this error. I also commented the **def **str** ** thought that was a problem.
I don't know what i can do about it? Please help

```
class Main(models.Model):
    website = models.CharField(db_column='Website', unique=True, max_length=250)
    main = models.CharField(db_column='Main', unique=True, max_length=100)
    tablename = models.CharField(db_column='TableName', unique=True, max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Main'

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.main

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.main)


class Child(models.Model):
    mainid = models.ForeignKey(Main, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='MainID')
    day = models.IntegerField(db_column='Day')
    hour = models.TimeField(db_column='HOUR')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Created_at')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Child'

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.mainid

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.mainid)
```

Thank you

Comment: which python version. Python 3 is unicode by default so why are u coercing the model into unicode?

Comment: i am using Python 2

Comment: Really, why not use python3? Anyways.. put this at the top of your script `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`

Comment: i have that at the top of each file

Comment: then you should not have the unicode method in your class again.

Comment: i didn't had it at first and gave that error

Comment: @savior123 the utf8 encoding at the top of the file is how the Python interpreter treats the text in the source code, and has nothing to do with how an object is represented as unicode (as I understand). If I am wrong can you point to some documentation where this is explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a main object to the unicode function. It expects a string of a buffer, but you are giving it an object.

Try changing your __unicode_ method in the Child. (There are a few ways that will work)

```
class Child(models.Model): 
    ...
    ...
    ..

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.mainid.__unicode__()
```

or this should work too by implicity caling the **unicode** method on the Main object.

```
     def __unicode__(self):
            return self.mainid
```

or this

```
     def __unicode__(self):
            return self.mainid.main
```

Not, that the __str__ method is what Python 3 uses whereas Python 2 uses __unicode__

Comment: i have tried all...and i also tried this:      def __unicode__(self):
        return '%mainid' % {'mainid': self.mainid}           It still gives me that error

Comment: I did remove the **def __str__**  from both of them

Comment: If you are using the third, most explicit version, then it should be giving a different error, as that error wouldn't make sense.

Comment: k i got it...it doesn't give me anymore the error...its gives the column main from Main....when i refresh the page..it print's them out...but in the shell...it still gives me that error

Comment: And i just found out if you change something in models... you have reload the shell in order to take effect...just found out that now :))) Thank you